# Display MySQL request in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make a basic todolist but i want to display a list with task undone at the top and the done at the bottom.
Every time i try i have a blank page

```
 <h1 class="header">To do.</h1>


 <?php if (!empty($items)): ?>



        <ul class="items">

 <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
<?php  if ( $item['done'] == 0 ) {
             echo '<li>';
             echo '<span class=\"item'?><?php echo $item['done'] ? ' done' : '' ?>"> <?php echo $item['name']; c</span>

 <?php if (!$item['done']): ?>
               <a href="app/mark.php?as=done&item=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" class="done-button">Mark as done</a>
             <?php endif; ?>


            </li>

 <?php endforeach; ?>


        </ul>

<?php else: ?>

        <p> No tasks</p>
```

I have a table items with a field Done (0,1)
I have tryed to put if condition in the foreach but it failed.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

At the **end** of your line which *begins* with `echo '<span class=\"item'?>` you set a PHP open tag but without closing it and then open another one on the next line:

```
<?php echo $item['name']; c</span>

<?php if (!$item['done']): ?>
```

It looks like you meant to close the PHP tag on the previous line with `?>`.

---

As a side suggestion, if you use a good editor or IDE it will show you errors on front of you as you type, saves a lot of time.

Viewing your PHP error logs is a must as a developer, as it tells you of problems as you work, and this would have shown a fatal error and the line number etc.
A white page is also a sign that you have a fatal error as PHP crashes before it will output any content to the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but every time i try to modify ny code i have a blank page :/

Comment: You need to start reading your PHP error log file, it will tell you what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

When i remove the if 
The code is working

```
 <?php if (!empty($items)): ?>



        <ul class="items">

 <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>

            <li>

<span class="item<?php echo $item['done'] ? ' done' : '' ?>"> <?php echo $item['name']; ?> </span>

 <?php if (!$item['done']): ?>
               <a href="app/mark.php?as=done&item=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" class="done-button">Mark as done</a>
             <?php endif; ?>


            </li>

 <?php endforeach; ?>


        </ul>

<?php else: ?>

        <p> You have no task</p>
```